# Game goes on indefinitely

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve this problem:

Three players a,b and c play a tournament of table tennis with the following rules: the game is by turns, the winner of the match will play with the person left outside and the player that achieves two consecutive triumphs will be the winner of the tournament. In each match both opponents have the same probability of winning. The players a and b start playing.

1) Which is the probability that the tournament goes on indefinitely?

2) Which is the probability of winning the tournament for each player?

For 1) the result I arrived to has no sense but nonetheless I'll write what I've tried to do:

I can split up the sample space in two sets $\Omega=\{\text{game ends}\} \cup \{\text{game goes on forever}\}$, so if $A=\{\text{game goes on forever}\}$ and $B=\{\text{game ends}\}$, the probability of the event in 1) would then be $$P(A)=1-P(B)$$

If I define $A_k=\{\text{game ends at match number k}\}$, then $B=\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N} A_k$.

And we have that $$P(A_k)=P(A_k|E)P(E)+P(A_k|F)P(F) \tag1 $$ where $E=\{\text{a wins first match}\}$ and $F=\{\text{b wins first match}\}$, so $$(1)=\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

First thing that doesn't make sense to me: if $k=1$, then the probability of the game ending at the first match is $1$

Finally we have $$P(A)=1-P(B)$$$$=1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$$$=1-\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=-1$$

So I have a negative value for a probability, which is absolutely absurd.

Where am I messing up this problem?

I have no idea what to do in 2)

I would appreciate help and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've corrected it

Comment: Aren't you mixing up $A$ and $B$ somehow? The probability of the event in 1) is $P(B)$ not $P(A)$. And by $B=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}A_k$ you must mean $A=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}A_k$.

Comment: I can't make sense of your equation $$(1)=\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}\dfrac{1}{2}$$ What quantity is $(1)$ supposed to be?

Comment: (1) is just $P(A_k)$

Comment: By your definitions, "B = {game goes on forever}" and "$A_k$ = {game ends at match number k}", so your equation $B=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}A_k$ says that {game goes on forever} = $\bigcup_k$ {game ends at match number k}. Where is the typo?

Comment: I've corrected the typo, $A$ and $B$ where mixed up, but I still don't understand why my solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Q1$

P(game goes on indefinitely) = $\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac12....$ to infinity = $0$

$Q2$

$a$ and $b$ must have the same chance, so we can focus on $c$

Whatever happens in the first round, $c$ can win in the 3rd round with probability $\dfrac14$,

and since probabilities of successive losses thereafter is $\dfrac12$,
get next win in the $6th$ round with probability $\dfrac{1}{32}$, and so on.

This is an infinite series with $a = \dfrac14, r = \dfrac18$, and sum = $\dfrac{\dfrac14}{1 - \dfrac18}= \dfrac27$

The balance probabilities will be equally divided between $a$ and $b$ at $\dfrac{5}{14}$ each.

Comment: I understand your answer for 2), but I don't see how you arrive to your solution ar 1). And do you get ot see what am I doing wrong in 1)? I thought that calculating it by first calculating its complement was going to be easy, isn't its complement the union of the $A_k's$?

Comment: It is best to solve a problem in the simplest way. For (1), each game has a 1/2 chance of being indecisive, and  the limit of $(1/2)^n$ as $n$ tends to infinity is $0$.